# Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted please someone help me with this

Tags: error, poa

i attached link code on etherscan. and error code also

error: 
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x90d0d39a127e0693066cbc9a8a42fab20250753ead52724ab1760d7b4b458009

code: 
 https://etherscan.io/address/0xfecf0e91a193e8511ac83d8effda34ae4278f491#code

Comment: Could you please add the code of your contract to the post and as well as a link to the contract on Etherscan?

Comment: its little bit hard to add d contact, because its little bit big, so i added link. please sir if you can help me. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is in here (function `investInternal`):

```
 if(!earlyParticipantWhitelist[receiver].status) {
      throw;
 }
```

Receiver (the caller of the `buy` method), is not on the `earlyParticipantWhitelist`.

Thus, the transaction reverts

Comment: sir, what an i do now? this is already created nah? can i change this? how? please

Comment: It seems that only the owner can put you on the whitelist. Maybe you should contact support of the crowdsale

Comment: sir the problem is im the one who created this using poa wizard. actually tried a lot, according to your knowledge, if i remove the whitelist it will be able to invest for everyone? now, i can invest only the addresses i put as whitelist addresses. that's the problem sir. i dont know what to do :(

Comment: What you should do: accept my answer, create a new question with detailed information on what you want to do and what you know about it not working. Add the links you provided in this question as well.